# What is the purpose of some fields in DSL in Dasha?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dsl, dasha

I want to know for what we need following fields:

- node
- do
- digression
- disable
- goto
- next
- transitions
- set
- exit

```
node call_reason
{
    do
    {
        digression disable sayHi;
        goto next;
    }
    
    transitions
    {
        next: goto how_are_you;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, you are asking this question because you are a little bit confused about syntax, I'll try to make it clear.

#### Nodes and Transitions

DashaScript is the language for describing automated conversations. Basically, any conversation script consists of

- *nodes* - states of your conversation (please, see [node doc](https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/dasha-script-language/program-structure#node))
- *transitions* - relations between nodes that are described by conditions of switching from the current node to the another. There are three different kinds of transitions, e.g. *instant transition* that is used in code of your example (please, see [transitions doc](https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/dasha-script-language/program-structure#transitions)).

In some sense, the scripted conversation can be thought of as a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)). In this case, *nodes* and *transitions* can be interpreted as *vertices* and *edges* of a graph, respectively.

Hence, `node` and `transition` define the structure of your conversation script.

Every `node` has subsection `do` where you can specify actions and instructions you want to be performed in this particular `node`.

Also, `node` may have subsection `transitions` which is used to specify conditions of switching a current state to another.  
Every event-transition (like transition on event and timer transition) specified in this section has the following syntax: `<transition_name>: goto <node_name> on <switching_condition>`.

Instant transitions (like the one used in your code) have no conditions: `<transition_name>: goto <node_name>`. To execute such transition, it must be called in section `do` of current node with `goto` instruction.

Also, there are special nodes that can be visited from any state. These nodes are called digressions. (see [digressions doc](https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/dasha-script-language/program-structure/#digression)). They are used to make fast reactions in your conversation and return to main branch of conversation. To control digression, we have mechanism of enabling/disabling them (see [digression-control doc](https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/dasha-script-language/program-structure/#digression-control)).

So, in your example, the `node` with name `call_reason` has section `do` where you `disable` degression-node and then instant transition with name `next` is executed.

All entities of DashaScript language mentioned above are described in [program structure docs](https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/dasha-script-language/program-structure). I would recommend you to check it out, since there are more important entities that you might need to know about.

#### Set

`set` is the instruction that is used for assigning a value for some variable. Example:

```
node some_node
{
    do {
        var some_variable: number = 1;
        set some_variable = 2; // now some_variable has value of 2
    }
}
```

#### Exit

`exit` is the instruction that interrupts the dialog.